# I can't install Enterprise root CA in windows 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I am trying to install Enterprise CA in my windows server 2003.But I can select only stand alone root CA and the stand alone subordinate CA. Other two options are not highlighted. Can anybody give me the possible reasons for it? Thanks in advance.(I don't have much understanding of the concepts related to certificates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be logged in with an account that is both an Enterprise admin, and in the Root domain's Domain Admins groups.  You may want to login as the actual Administrator account for your domain, to do this, since it will be a member of the require groups.  The process needs to make changes to the domain and forest, so it requires more privileges, then normally needed for day-to-day operations.

The machine should not be a Domain controller or have any other services installed.

You must have the computer name set to what it is going to be for the life of the CA.  You cannot change the computer name without taking the CA offline.

Before doing anything you should take time to make sure the CA machine is extremely secure, apply all appropriate patches, and follow standard security hardening procedures.